# How to copy every thing after a tag in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Working on a homework assignment, I have "doc.html" file with data:

```
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> Automated Scalable Bayesian Inference via Hilbert Coresets
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> PASS-GLM: polynomial approximate sufficient statistics for scalable  Bayesian GLM inference
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> Covariances, Robustness, and Variational Bayes
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> Edge-exchangeable graphs and sparsity (NIPS 2016)
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> Fast Measurements of Robustness to Changing Priors in Variational Bayes
<span class="descriptor">Title:</span> Boosting Variational Inference
```

For each line, I am trying to get any thing after `</span>` - so the expected output should be:

```
Automated Scalable Bayesian Inference via Hilbert Coresets
PASS-GLM: polynomial approximate sufficient statistics for scalable  Bayesian GLM inference
Covariances, Robustness, and Variational Bayes
Edge-exchangeable graphs and sparsity (NIPS 2016)
Fast Measurements of Robustness to Changing Priors in Variational Bayes
Boosting Variational Inference
```

I tried below code (not working).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("doc.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    for line in soup.find_all('span'):
        print line.get_text()
```

What is the missing piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `nextSibling` of your span element and not the `text` inside span!

Note: Use strip() to remove the trailing newline.

```
>>> with open("doc.html") as fp:
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
...     for line in soup.find_all('span'):
...         print line.nextSibling.strip()
... 
Automated Scalable Bayesian Inference via Hilbert Coresets
PASS-GLM: polynomial approximate sufficient statistics for scalable  Bayesian GLM inference
Covariances, Robustness, and Variational Bayes
Edge-exchangeable graphs and sparsity (NIPS 2016)
Fast Measurements of Robustness to Changing Priors in Variational Bayes
Boosting Variational Inference
>>>
```